# How to solve (bidirectional) parent/child relationchip in iBATIS

Tags: orm, ibatis, mybatis

Let's say I have two simple tables:

```
Article: id | text
Comment: id | articleId | text
```

two DTO classes:

```
class Article {
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private List<Comment> comments;
    ...
}

class Comment {
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private Article article;
    ...
}
```

And I would like to select an article by the id with all of its comments. The crucial requirement is that the Article instance returned from the query has to be the SAME instance as in all its comments getArticle().

Is is possible to map this at all? The mapping I can think of:

```
<resultMap id="ArticleResult" class="Article">
    <result column="id" property="id" />
    <result column="text" property="text" />
            <result column="id" property="comments" select="findCommentsByArticleId" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="CommentResult" class="Comment">
    <result column="id" property="id" />
    <result column="text" property="text" />
    <result column="articleId" property="article" select="findArticleById" />
</resultMap>

<select id="findArticleById" resultMap="ArticleResult" parameterClass="int">
    SELECT * FROM Article WHERE id = #value#
</select>

<select id="findCommentsByArticleId" resultMap="CommentResult" parameterClass="int">
    SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE articleId = #value#
</select>
```

But first, it looks like a cycle to me and second, the crucial requirement I mention above would be not met.

Comment: Bidrectional relationships are difficult to maintain. Does it have to be this in your case? I mean it's much easier if you could remove the List<Comment> comments in Article and replace the object navigation with a database query.

Comment: Well, the Article is then forwarded to another (Model-view-controller) framework, so it has to be like that. I'm doing it now in the DAO layer, but I would like to know if the iBATIS has a support for this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think?  please vote:

I believe the key is that in the resultMap, and should be used instead of  `<result>`.

```
<resultMap id="ParentResult" groupBy="id">
    <result property="id" column="ID" />
    ...
    <collection property="children" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Child" resultMap="ChildResult" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="ChildResult">
    <result property="id" column="ID" />
    <association property="parentId" foreignColumn="PARENT_ID" resultMap="ParentResult" />
    ...
</result>
```